# Nowrap breaks flex bounds

Tags: css, flexbox

I've tried multiple solutions for this problem but none of them worked for me. ***(the min-width hack)***

Here's a live example of my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/d3d9ph9q/3/

As you can see, when i have long text that i want to shrink with an ellipsis it just breaks out of the box as soon as i apply `white-space: nowrap`

Could someone possibly point out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this what you want:  https://jsfiddle.net/d3d9ph9q/1/

Comment: @Michael_B Sorry updated - the min-width trick doesn't work when the flex box is within another flex box.

Comment: Re: `min-width`, it's not a trick or a hack. It's just overriding an initial setting defined by the spec. And it works fine in your layout: https://jsfiddle.net/d3d9ph9q/4/

Comment: @Michael_B Oh wow Thanks so much!, I didn't know I had to put it in the parent flex boxes too. wish I could select your answer but it's just a comment!

Comment: An initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that a flex item is not permitted to be smaller than the length of its content. You can override that setting with `min-width: 0` or `overflow` with any value other than `visible`.

Comment: You may be overlooking the fact that a flex container can also be a flex item in a larger container, which is the case in your code.

Comment: Really appreciate the clarification Michael!